# How to decode a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mandrill

I am working with the Mandrill Inbound Email API, and when an email has an attachment with one or more spaces in its file name, then the file name is encoded in a format that I do not know how to decode.

Here is a an example string I receive for the file name: `=?UTF-8?B?TWlzc2lvbmFyecKgRmFpdGjCoFByb21pc2XCoGFuZMKgQ2FzaMKgUmVjZWlwdHPCoFlURMKgMjUzNQ==?= =?UTF-8?B?OTnCoEp1bHktMjAxNS5jc3Y=?=`

I tried `Base64.decode64(#{encoded_value})` but that didn't return a readable text.

How do I decode that value into a readable string?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would tell us which algorithm you are talking about.

Comment: Use mime decoder, just a clue for you: `puts Base64.decode64("TWlzc2lvbmFyecKgRmFpdGjCoFByb21pc2XCoGFuZMKgQ2FzaMKgUmVjZWlwdHPCoFlURMKgMjUzNQ==")` produce `Missionary Faith Promise and Cash Receipts YTD 2535`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [MIME encoded-word syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) as defined in [RFC-2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822). From Wikipedia:

> The form is: "`=?`*charset*`?`*encoding*`?`*encoded text*`?=`".
>
> - *charset* may be any character set registered with [IANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority). Typically it would be the same charset as the message body.
> - *encoding* can be either "`Q`" denoting Q-encoding that is similar to the [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding, or "`B`" denoting [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding.
> - *encoded text* is the Q-encoded or base64-encoded text.

Fortunately you don't need to write a decoder for this. The [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem comes with a [`Mail::Encodings.value_decode`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mail/Mail/Encodings#value_decode-class_method) method that works perfectly and is very [well-tested](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/f0efbd4850d1bc06cdcba6178c282eeaba9c8c43/spec/mail/encodings_spec.rb#L114-L19):

```
subject = "=?UTF-8?B?TWlzc2lvbmFyecKgRmFpdGjCoFByb21pc2XCoGFuZMKgQ2FzaMKgUmVjZWlwdHPCoFlURMKgMjUzNQ==?= =?UTF-8?B?OTnCoEp1bHktMjAxNS5jc3Y=?="
Mail::Encodings.value_decode(subject)
# => "Missionary Faith Promise and Cash Receipts YTD 253599 July-2015.csv"
```

It gracefully handles lots of edge cases you probably wouldn't think of (until your app tries to handle them and falls over):

```
subject = "Re:[=?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCJTAlayE8JV0lcyEmJTglYyVRJXMzdDwwMnEbKEI=?=\n =?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCPFIbKEI=?=] =?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCSlY/LiEnGyhC?=\n  =?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCIVolMCVrITwlXSVzIVskKkxkJCQ5ZyRvJDsbKEI=?=\n =?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCJE43byRLJEQkJCRGIUolaiUvJSglOSVIGyhC?=#1056273\n =?iso-2022-jp?B?GyRCIUsbKEI=?="
Mail::Encodings.value_decode(subject)
# => "Re:[グルーポン・ジャパン株式会社] 返信：【グルーポン】お問い合わせの件について（リクエスト#1056273\n ）"
```

If you're using Rails you already have the Mail gem. Otherwise just add `gem "mail"` to your Gemfile, then `bundle install` and, in your script, `require "mail"`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment from @Yevgeniy-Anfilofyev who pointed me in the right direction, I was able to write the following method that correctly parsed the encoded value and returned an ASCII string.

```
def self.decode(value)
  # It turns out the value is made up of multiple encoded parts
  # so we first need to split each part so we can decode them seperately
  encoded_parts = name.split('=?UTF-8?B?').
                       map{|x| x.sub(/\?.*$/, '') }.
                       delete_if{|x| x.blank? }

  encoded_parts.map{|x| Base64.decode64(x)}. # decode each part
                join(''). # join the parts together
                force_encoding('utf-8'). # force UTF-8 encoding
                gsub("\xC2\xA0", " ") # remove the UTF-8 encoded spaces with an ASCII space
end
```

Comment: Won't this code fail when the encoding isn't UTF-8?